# What does "%lld\n" mean?

Tags: c

Can you please explain to me what these lines do?

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long) time(NULL));

printf("%.2x", (unsigned char)key[i]);
```

Comment: Have you tried this on console.?

Answer (score 1):

`%lld` means "print long long int variable".

`%.2x` means "print two hexadecimal digits".

Note, however, that these two lines of code are undefined behavior, as you have not supplied an argument corresponding to the format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

%lld means long long dword
%.2x will print dot and 2 hex digits from the variable you chose (it will 0 pad in case it is less than 10)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

I've found useful this sheet (https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/DataTypesSummary.pdf)

For those who come from java background for what I understand it is some kind of casting (format) before printing a variable. It also requires to specify the variable type (unsigned char).

printf(""%.2x ", (unsigned char) key[i]) -----> printf = (JAVA) simple printout (sout)

Note: In case you need to save the new variable with you can use snprintf

snprintf(str[i], 128, "%.2x",  key[i]); -----> snprintf = (JAVA) str is a new array where key[i] is saved with "%.2x" format